# Wordpress URL redirect

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, site-url

I have a wordpress page at `http://www.mysiteurl.com/pagename/` and I want any URL of the form `http://www.mysiteurl.com/pagename/{any string here}` to redirect or display my original page. How do I go about doing this? Is there a wordpress plugin that will make this simple for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite possible. First off, Making `pagename/{customString}` resolve as the page itself instead of 404, then, you're free to decide whether to keep the URI as is and serve the page content, or redirect back somewhere e.g page permalink ( `get_the_permalink()` ):

```
add_action( "init", function(){
    $pagename = "pagename"; // page slug
    add_rewrite_rule(
        sprintf('^%s/([^/]*)/?', $pagename),
        sprintf('index.php?pagename=%s&pageParam=$matches[1]', $pagename),
        'top'
    );
});

add_filter( "query_vars", function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "pageParam";
    return $vars;
});

add_action( "template_redirect", function(){
    if ( $param = get_query_var( "pageParam" ) ) {
        /* make sure param is not for comments pagination or smth similar */ 
        wp_redirect( get_the_permalink(), 301 );
        exit;
    }
});
```

If you don't wish to have the redirect then remove the code hooked into `template_redirect` (as of line:15). To get that custom string ( `{any string here}` ), simply call `get_query_var( "pageParam" )`.

Hope that helps.